# Websites providing visual weather data

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, weather-forecasting, visualization

What websites are there providing visual weather data? The question actually contains the past and future weather. The purpose is for this question is to provide a list of easy-to-access websites that give a weather enthusiast/researcher overview of the weather at a given time. Please list what models the website uses and other describing information.

Ps. I think this should be a community wiki question and answer so that the list can be updated. So feel free to edit this question too.

Comment: The thing that makes this question a struggle is defining what you mean by visual weather data.  Any forecast map/radar/satellite/model plot/etc is visual weather data.  Plus over the expanse of the world, there are a whole lot of local websites that offer unique things.  I've been building a loose (mostly US-centric) list since your post... but not sure it really answers your question, especially if you are looking for other sites like your example.

Answer (score 3):

**[weather.us](https://weather.us/model-charts/euro)**

- If somebody is looking for free global ECMWF forecasts the above site provides a fairly complete set of links that provide information 10 days into the future. You can track the control member(which I believe is a deterministic forecast) and also the ensemble output.  In addition you can look at worldwide lightning detection sites as well as radar images of US and other selected countries. For followers of tropical meteorology  hurricane tracks of ECMWF are also available - [ECMWF  cyclone tracks](https://weather.us/cyclone-tracks). 
  The availability of free ECMWF forecasts comes via the courtesy of Jörg Kachelmann who owns the site.

Comment: Hadn't seen that one before, nice.  But unless I've missed something, I can't imagine he can keep providing that.  It doesn't appear he's directly connected with the ECMWF, and have seen others doing similar kindly asked to take it down over time.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - yes I exchanged notes with him on another forum and he said he is doing it for the benefit of humanity whatever that means. The initiative is venture funded so there is support for this as long as it does come.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest [It's all paid for](https://twitter.com/RyanMaue/status/919371591536009217), although I'm not sure how...

Comment: @hichris123 considering not even the big multinational companies are able to manage to distribute the full ECM publicly, I don't see how.  Worked with European group for quite a few years... they aren't exactly friendly and helpful.  So while I'm not saying it's impossible, the incredible cost + ECMWF's tight attitude make me think it won't last long.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - my guess is that the repackaged forecast maybe sold somewhere. That brings in the profits.

Answer (score 3):

For forecasting, there is a ton of data on the internet. Here are just a few sources.

- A Penn State professor compiled a list of weather websites on a webpage
  called [National Weather Connections](http://www.meteo.psu.edu/~j2n/natlwx.htm). I'd explore that.
- The [Penn State E-wall](http://mp1.met.psu.edu/~fxg1/ewall.html) is commonly used, primarily for forecasts.
  The NARR tab has visual data all the way back to 1979, while the
  primary page has operational model data.
- [Twister data](http://www.twisterdata.com/) primarily has forecast data, but also has a nice
  feature to plot Skew-Ts.
- [Accuweather Pro](https://wwwl.accuweather.com/pro_login.php) probably is one of the most complete forecasting
  websites around. The downside is that you have to pay a subscription.
- [Tropical tidbits](https://www.tropicaltidbits.com/) is a useful forecasting website too.
- [BUFKIT](http://training.weather.gov/wdtd/tools/BUFKIT/index.php) with pages providing the data, is a well established
  tool.
- NCEP also has an [SREF Plume viewer](http://www.spc.noaa.gov/exper/sref/srefplumes/) and a [GEFS plume viewer](http://www.emc.ncep.noaa.gov/mmb/cguastini/gefs/EMCGEFSplumes.html).

Unfortunately, there aren't too many places with archived data is a visually appealing manor. One reason for that is that there is enough data for just forecasting, that it is hard to keep up with it.

- University of Wyoming has a [soundings archive](http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html) that is useful.
- [Downloadable archived Radar data](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/nexradinv/) is able to be viewed using the
  [Weather and climate toolkit](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/).
- Though I haven't used it extensively, I did find an [NCDC GIS product
  with radar data](https://gis.ncdc.noaa.gov/maps/ncei/radar).
- The NOHRSC has an interactive satellite-derived [map to show snow
  depth](https://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/interactive/html/map.html).
- While it isn't exactly perfect, the [Wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/)
  intermittently archives images of websites. Sometimes it works.
  Sometimes it doesn't.
- The [WPC weather map archive](http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/web_pages/sfc/sfc_archive.php) can also give a synoptic flavor to
  previous weather.
- [This NCAR image archive sometimes works.](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/imagearchive/)

There are many, many more websites. Yet, the best products are ones you design yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**[VentuSky](http://www.ventusky.com)**:

- Uses ICON, GFS, GEM (global) and HRRR (US) models with respective forecast times 4, 9, 9 and 2 days respectively. Map can be played as animation. Animation and weather map settings can be changed by the user. Map is zoom-able. Has nice customizable wind animation. Is made by a Czech Republic company called InMeteo.

Please add more to this community post. Also previous posts can be edited f.e. if some attribute is in all websites it is probably unnecessary to mention.